# Laravel API Testing always returning middleware error

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

I have created laravel backend related few of end points. how ever when I trying to test it using unit testing always returning 'Get the application's route middleware groups' error. Please help me to resolve this.

**my test file is**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Laravel\Sanctum\Sanctum;
use Tests\TestCase;

class FetchDamageRequestListTest extends TestCase
{
public function test_fetch_damage_request_list()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $payload = [
    ];
    $headers = [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ];

    $user = Sanctum::actingAs(User::factory()->create(),['*']);

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)- 
    >post('/api/web/v1/fetch_dashboard_info',$payload, $headers);
    $response->assertStatus(200);
   }
 }
```

**my routes**

```
<?php

 use App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\DamageReportController;
 use App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\DashboardController;
 use App\Http\Controllers\API\V1\UserController;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

 Route::post('login', [UserController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
 Route::post('logout', [UserController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
   Route::post('save_damage_request', [DamageReportController::class, 
   'saveDamageReportRequest'])->name('save_damage_request');
   Route::post('fetch_damage_request', [DamageReportController::class, 
   'fetchDamageReportRequest'])->name('fetch_damage_request');
   Route::post('fetch_damage_request_details', [DamageReportController::class, 
   'fetchDamageReportRequestDetails']);
   Route::post('approve_damage_request', [DamageReportController::class, 
   'approveDamageReportRequest']);
   Route::post('fetch_damage_request_reason', [DamageReportController::class, 
   'fetchDamageReportReason']);
   Route::post('reject_damage_request', [DamageReportController::class, 
   'rejectDamageReportRequest']);

   Route::post('fetch_dashboard_info', [DashboardController::class, 
   'fetchDashboardInfo']);
});
```

**The error is**
[image]

Comment: The issue is not a middleware but that the route is not found... You are trying to use `/api/web/v1/fetch_dashboard_info`, but your route (I am not sure if it is `api.php` route) is just `fetch_dashboard_info`, could you share you `RouteServiceProvider` so we can see if all the prefixes are in there?

Comment: My api.php is
`Route::prefix('web')->group(function () {
    Route::prefix('v1')->group(function () {
        require_once('api/web/v1.php');
    });
});`

Comment: That is the problem, you have `prefix('web')`, that means your URLs are going to be `domain.com/web/v1/xxxxx`, not `domain.com/api/v1/xxxx`

Answer (score 0):

The test file is wrong I think. I'm providing a new test file to test the authentication is working or not.
Try this:

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AuthenticationTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_api_tokens_can_be_created()
    {
        $this->actingAs($user = User::factory()->create());
        
        $this->assertAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

For your case,

```php
$response = $this->post('/api/web/v1/fetch_dashboard_info', [
// insert payload data here
]);
```

No need to add headers again. After authentication, the session manager will handle it.

Comment: He is not testing authentication. Never do/use solution 2, as if that is not working, your test will fail and will stop the test, and if the login behavior changes, you will have to update the test when in reality you are not trying to test that. A test **ONLY** tests one single unit of work, in this case `/api/web/v1/fetch_dashboard_info`